# Pull Down to Update functionality in Flash for IOS/Android

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I want to implement the scroll down to refresh functionality like facebook IOS app in my IOS app. But have no idea how to implement it in flash. If anyone have any Idea, please share with me.

Comment: I have a recycle scroll list, on which i have tried to implement this functionality, but dont know why my item renderers are not updating/ not removing - adding in a proper way. if you want to look at that scroll you can visit : 

https://github.com/thanksmister/as3recyclelist

i have used this scroll and trying to implent that function on this scroll.

Comment: Found this by searching on google, a coworker had used it before: http://www.riagora.com/2011/05/pull-down-to-refresh/

Comment: Thank you for for your time Sunil, but that component is in flash, i have to code only in actionscript 3.0 :(, my project's basic requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think one possible solution can be
If you are using a list item and you'll notice as you pull the list down the height of the component (scroll area) increased (the only time, height will increase). You can try to get the initial height and add an event listener on change of component height, send your server request for new data. I haven't use as3 for a while, but try something like this.

```
1. Store initial list height
2. add an event listener on initialise() of the view; For the event listener you can even use swipe down(event.offsetY) method and look for height change.
3. on change of height (i.e increased), send new request to server
```

Post the code if you try, We may solve it together.